# Read Datatables JSON POST with PHP

Tags: php, json, datatables

Trying to read an ajax POST from DataTables in my own PHP server script. Here is what Chrome shows me as the form data that is posted:

> data[633474][username]: sample@email.org
> data[633474][passwd]: 
> data[633474][fname]: Sample
> data[633474][lname]: Person
> data[633474][cell]: 555-555-1234
> data[633474][assignment]: 7892
> data[633474][usertype]: Report
> action: edit

I need to get the number (in this example, 633474) as well as the various values into PHP variables. The number (633474) will vary. I have tried a variety of json_decode and PHP array functions but am not finding the secret sauce here.

The number is the row ID that datatables uses, so maybe there is a way to tell datatables to POST the data differently. But I am completely confused at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I got you right this should get you the number. Next time please google first.

```
// Follow security rules here
$data = $_POST['data'];

// Note that array_keys() returns an array with possibly
// more than one numbers (maybe that's your plan)
$rowID = array_keys($data)[0];

// returns int(633474)
var_dump($rowID);exit;
```

Comment: Thanks -- but I've been googling for two days. But apparently my eyes are just crossed from staring at the screen too long. For posterity's sake -- Marco M's solution does work. PHP seems to recognize that POST format as an array automatically without having to declare it as an array.

Comment: Glad I could help ;) And yes, PHP already casts that to arrays. But be careful that field values like "7892" are strings and not automatically casted to anything.